# workflow fires two times even if i do not change field value in CRM 2011

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a workflow in Microsoft CRM 2011 that fires on a certain field change.
When this workflow fires, it will first check the boolean value of flag: if the value is *yes* then set it to *no* otherwise if flag value is *no* then create another "XYZ" entity.

**My problem is**: when I change flag value to *no* it again fires and create another entity "XYZ".

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because your plugin is looping infinitely, as it triggers itself over and over again.

You can prevent the loop using the IExecutionContext.Depth property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iexecutioncontext.depth.aspx

```
IPluginExecutionContext context = IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

if (context.Depth > 1) { return; }
```

This will cancel your plugin when your depth is deeper than 1.